# get stage.stageHeight or stage.stageWidth from imported class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

can you tell me a simple and clean way to pass the dimension of the stage to another class, imported in my documentclass?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting these two lines in the constructor of the Class that you want to use the stage width/height:

```
if (stage) init();
else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
```

Make sure you import the `flash.events.Event` class.

Then create this method inside the same Class:

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    trace(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}
```

This `init` method will be called only when your class is added to the stage. This means the stage variable will be accessible (not null).

This is just a test to show that the stage object is only available when the displayObject is added to the display list.